# Bash-Variable subsitution in Makefile subshell

Tags: bash, make, docker-compose

My Makefile should and does create a file `/tmp/file` in the docker container using `make test`:

```
test:   
    (cd subdirectory && docker-compose exec webserver bash -c "\
        MYTEXT=hello && \
        echo 'this is $$MYTEXT world' > /tmp/file && \
        cat /tmp/file
    ")
```

But this doesn't work as expected. `/tmp/file` has content:

```
this is  world
```

But I would expect it to be

```
this is hello world
```

How to pass MYTEXT to the next command (`echo`)?

Comment: The single quote in your command will mean that at best you will get 'this is $MYTEXT world' in your file. The `(` and `)` add nothing except load to your system. Is the `webserver` container running, i.e. does `docker exec webserver /bin/true` succeed or give an error?

Comment: @icarus Yes, the container is running. How should the echo command be written instead?

Comment: `cd subdirectory && docker exec webserver bash -c 'MYTEXT=hello; echo "this is $$MYTEXT world" >/tmp/file'`  works for me. Note using docker rather than docker-compose and swapping the single and double quotes and removal of the `()`.

Comment: What have you done to debug this?  (Obvious steps include running it without Docker, running it without the redirection (so the message appears on your terminal(?)), eliminating the variable and just doing `echo "hello world"`, eliminating the parentheses, doing the command in the terminal (outside of `make`), and doing everything in one line.) Do you get *any* output on your terminal? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' modified question to make it clearer.

Comment: you say "My Makefile should create a file `/tmp/file`" … "But this doesn't work. `make` test produces this `/tmp/file`". I am confused.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor sorry. I edited the questions and made it clearer now.

Answer (score 3):

`make` calls `sh` (by default, unless you change the `SHELL` `make` variable) to interpret the code (one `sh` invocation per line, unless you use `\` at the end of each line).

Here, you want `$$MYTEXT` so `$MYTEXT` be embedded in the `sh` code, but you also want that `$MYTEXT` not to be expanded by that `sh`, but be passed in the `bash` code, so that expansion must be prevented either with `\` inside the double-quotes, or use single-quotes instead of double-quotes. In any case, since you want `bash` to expand that `$MYTEXT`, you don't want `$MYTEXT` in the `bash` code to be in single-quotes.

So:

```
test:   
    (cd subdirectory && \
      docker-compose exec webserver bash -c '\
        MYTEXT=hello && \
        echo "this is $$MYTEXT world" > /tmp/file && \
        cat /tmp/file \
      '\
    )
```

If you run `strace -s999 -fe execve make`, you'll see (here with `docker-compose exec webserver bash` replaced with `bash`):

```
[pid 22370] execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh", "-c", "(cd subdirectory && \\\n  exec bash -c '\\\n    MYTEXT=hello && \\\n    echo \"this is $MYTEXT world\" > /tmp/file && \\\n    cat /tmp/file \\\n  '\\\n)"], 0x555ce503e620 /* 52 vars */) = 0
strace: Process 22371 attached
[pid 22371] execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "\\\n    MYTEXT=hello && \\\n    echo \"this is $MYTEXT world\" > /tmp/file && \\\n    cat /tmp/file \\\n  "], 0x563430f3e8f8 /* 52 vars */) = 0
[pid 22371] execve("/bin/cat", ["cat", "/tmp/file"], 0x55e9509edc10 /* 52 vars */) = 0
this is hello world
```

In any case, the subshell `(...)` is not necessary here as `cd` will only change the working directory of that one process running that one `sh` invocation, without affecting the working directory of any other shell run later on by `make` to run other commands.

Answer (score 0):

Take the script and get it working outside of make.

- run it through `shellcheck`
- test it

You will find a problem with quotes.

Comment: Sorry, but it's inside the Makefile that makes things harder because make has specific rules for variable subsititution.

Comment: Yes. And this is exactly why I say "Take the script and get it working outside of make". Trying to fix two types of error at the same time is to complex: complexity(a) × complexity(b)